# How can to change verts values in the curve model?

Tags: modeling

Hi Blender Developers and Users:

I have curve models with ply format as following specifications:

Verts: 177, Faces: 0; Tris: 0;

For example, I want change verts value from 177 to 200 (increasing)or to 150 (decreasing). 
In other words, I want to interpolate points in these models.

How can I do it?

Please guide me;
Shahrokh

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't directly affect the vertices created by curves without writing those curves to mesh (alt c -> mesh from curve.)

However, you can increase or decrease the number of vertices created by a curve.  Increasing the resolution of the curve in properties/data/shape will create additional vertices along the length of a curve.  If your curve has a bevel, increasing its resolution creates additional vertices along the radius of the bevel.  If your object is using a bevel object, you can change the resolution of the bevel object instead.